# How can I prove that the following two trinangles are similar?

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is an inclined plane situation in physics... How can I prove the similarity of the angles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: drawing made using GeoGebra]

Draw a line $(\rm D)$ parallel to that side of the triangle. Now the angle $\angle\rm HAB$ is equal to $\alpha$. Consider now the triangle $\triangle\rm CAB$. The angle $\angle\rm CAB$ is $90^\circ\!\!$, hence the angle $\angle\rm CAH$ is $90^\circ-\alpha$. And since the angles of a triangle sum up to $180^\circ\!\!$, $$\rm\angle CAH+\angle AHC+\angle ACH=180^\circ\implies \angle ACH=180^\circ-\Big(\angle CAH+\angle AHC\Big),$$ and since $\angle\rm AHC=90^\circ\!\!$, it follows that $\angle\rm ACH=\alpha$.

Comment: Genius ! thanks a lot

Comment: @therue You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ahn1ym think this one is a bit easier...

Comment: @therue Indeed, it is faster.

Comment: If a line is parallel to one side of a triangle and intersects the other two sides of the triangle, the line divides these two sides proportionally.

Comment: used this to prove for beta... anyways thanks for everything haha